# Results from search not shown in iframe (using switch statement)

Tags: php, html, iframe, phpmyadmin

We are using a switch statement to switch between languages but when we try to use case 1(the dutch/nl flag), the results no longer shows up. Everything works fine without using the switch case, however.

This is our index

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Welcome to Medispeak</title>
  <link rel=stylesheet href=Medi.css>
</head>

<body>
<header>

  <div class="lang">
    <form method="GET" action="?set=lang">
      <input id="vlag" name="lang" class="nl" type="submit" value="1">
      <input id="vlag" name="lang" class="en" type="submit" value="2">
      <input id="vlag" name="lang" class="du" type="submit" value="3">
      <input id="vlag" name="lang" class="es" type="submit" value="4">
      <input id="vlag" name="lang" class="pt" type="submit" value="5">
      <input id="vlag" name="lang" class="fr" type="submit" value="6">
    </form>
  </div>
</header>
    <h1>Zoeken op Medicijn</h1>
  <form method="post" action="tabel.php" target="Mediframe">
    Voer medicijn in:
    <input type="text" name="zoek">
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="zoeken">
    <input type="reset" value="wissen">
  </form>
  <div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
      <iframe name="Mediframe" width="800" height="600" frameborder=0>
      </iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This is our search function:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Medispeak</title>
    <link rel=stylesheet href=ProjectCSS.css>
  </head>

  <body>

    <?php
    include 'db.php';
    print_r($_REQUEST);

    $zoek = $_REQUEST['zoek'];
    $lang = $_REQUEST['lang'];
    if ( empty ( $lang ) ) { $lang = "1"; } 
    switch ($lang) {
    case "1":
echo 'case1';
      try
      {
        $sQuery= "SELECT Medibijsluiter
        FROM Medispeak
        WHERE Medinaam LIKE ?";

        $oStmt = $db->prepare($sQuery);
        $oStmt->bindValue(1, "%$zoek%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $oStmt->execute();
        if($oStmt->rowCount()>0)

        {
            echo '<table border="2">';
            echo '<thead>';
            echo '<td>Medibijsluiter</td>';
            echo '</thead>';
            while($aRow = $oStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
          {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$aRow['Medibijsluiter'].'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
          }
          echo '</table>';
       }
       else
       {
        echo 'Helaas,geen gegevens bekend';
       }

        break;
     }
    }

    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    $sMsg = '<p>
        Regelnummer: '.$e->getLine().'<br />
        Bestand: '.$e->getFile().'<br />
        Foutmelding: '.$e->getMessage().'
        </p>';

         trigger_error($sMsg);
    }
    $db = null;
    ?>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why have a switch with only one case? Also you have HTML in the head instead of body

Comment: We're planning to add more cases but can't even get the first to work properly

Comment: 1: Add error handling, 2: Your catch needs to be after the try and not after the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **$_GET['lang']** instead of **$_POST['lang']**. Or you can user **$_REQUEST['zoek']** and **$_REQUEST['lang']**.

If you have form type as ***GET***, then the form data can be accessed using **$_GET** or **$_REQUEST**. If the type is ***POST***, you should use either **$_POST** or **$_REQUEST**.

[Read this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) to know more about GET, POST and REQUEST in PHP

So change your code

```
$zoek = $_POST['zoek'];
switch ($_GET['lang']) {
```

**or**

```
$zoek = $_REQUEST['zoek'];
switch ($_REQUEST['lang']) {
```

**Updated Code**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Welcome to Medispeak</title>
  <link rel=stylesheet href=Medi.css>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(!empty($_REQUEST['zoek'])) {
    $zoek = $_REQUEST['zoek'];
    include 'db.php';
    $lang = $_REQUEST['lang'];

    if ( empty ( $lang ) ) { $lang = "1"; } 

    switch ($lang) {
        case "1":
          echo 'case1';
          try
          {
             $sQuery= "SELECT Medibijsluiter FROM Medispeak WHERE Medinaam LIKE ?";
         $oStmt = $db->prepare($sQuery);
         $oStmt->bindValue(1, "%$zoek%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
         $oStmt->execute();
            if($oStmt->rowCount()>0)
            {
                echo '<table border="2"><thead><td>Medibijsluiter</td></thead>';

                while($aRow = $oStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                {
               echo '<tr><td>'.$aRow['Medibijsluiter'].'</td></tr>';
                }

                echo '</table>';
            } else {
            echo 'Helaas,geen gegevens bekend';
            }

         break;
       }

       catch(PDOException $e) {
        $sMsg = '<p>
            Regelnummer: '.$e->getLine().'<br />
            Bestand: '.$e->getFile().'<br />
            Foutmelding: '.$e->getMessage().'
            </p>';
            trigger_error($sMsg);
        }
    }

    $db = null;
}
?>
<header>
  <div class="lang">
    <form method="GET" action="?set=lang">
      <input id="vlag" name="lang" class="nl" type="submit" value="1">
      <input id="vlag" name="lang" class="en" type="submit" value="2">
      <input id="vlag" name="lang" class="du" type="submit" value="3">
      <input id="vlag" name="lang" class="es" type="submit" value="4">
      <input id="vlag" name="lang" class="pt" type="submit" value="5">
      <input id="vlag" name="lang" class="fr" type="submit" value="6">
    </form>
  </div>
</header>
    <h1>Zoeken op Medicijn</h1>
  <form method="post" action="" target="Mediframe">
    Voer medicijn in:
    <input type="text" name="zoek">
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="zoeken">
    <input type="reset" value="wissen">
  </form>
  <div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
      <iframe name="Mediframe" width="800" height="600" frameborder=0>
      </iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

> Update this code in index file. tabel.php content also added in this
>   file. So the form will be submitted to the same page and it will not
>   refer tabel.php.

Comment: Tried switching both to $_REQUEST, it still didn't work.

Comment: Add `print_r($_REQUEST);` below `include 'db.php';` and run your page and share the output. Also make sure you just clicked the language buttons. Else you will get empty array. Try this code.

`$zoek = $_REQUEST['zoek'];
$lang = $_REQUEST['lang'];

if ( empty ( $lang ) ) { $lang = 1; }

switch ($lang) {`

Comment: follow the steps updated in my previous comment. That code will give you the result of language1, by default.

Comment: I've added it but I still get nothing; the $lang doesn't get set to 1

Comment: Update your code in question. So that I can see the changes

Comment: Done. The $lang gets set to 1 now but it still doesn't give any output

Comment: I have added sample code in case1. Check and update the code and let me know whether you are getting the message 'case1' after submitting the form

Comment: No, when I submit the form nothing shows up at all.

Comment: please see my answer below -- you have two seperate forms, so when submitting the "search form", whatever you do in the "language form" won't be sent along.

Comment: @Hi.. M New, I have updated the code in my answer. Just copy and replace in your index file and check.

Comment: Thank you very much, the switch cases work now. However, the search form appears a second time in the i-frame whenever something is searched.

Comment: great!! so you want to display only the table after submitting the form? and don't want to display the language numbers and search form?

Comment: Then add `die;` after `$db = null;` and check

Answer (score 0):

You're using two different forms, one for language selection and one for searching. Thus, when submitting the second form whatever you selected in the first one gets completely ignored. (Additionally, the first form is using $_GET, and you're looking for the language in $_POST)

A quick fix would be moving your language selection element into the second form, so the selected language gets send along with the search phrase.

Answer (score 0):

change `switch ($_POST['lang'])` to `switch ($_GET['lang'])` you mix up POST and GET with your two forms

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome to Medispeak</title>
    <link rel=stylesheet href=Medi.css>
</head>


<body>
<header>
    <div class="lang">
        <form method="GET" action="?set=lang">
            <input id="vlag" name="lang" class="nl" type="submit" value="1">
        <input id="vlag" name="lang" class="en" type="submit" value="2">
        <input id="vlag" name="lang" class="du" type="submit" value="3">
        <input id="vlag" name="lang" class="es" type="submit" value="4">
        <input id="vlag" name="lang" class="pt" type="submit" value="5">
        <input id="vlag" name="lang" class="fr" type="submit" value="6">
    </form>
</div>
</header>
    <form method="post" action="tabel.php" target="Mediframe">
    <h1>Zoeken op Medicijn</h1>
Voer medicijn in:
   <input type="text" name="zoek">
   <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="zoeken">
<input type="reset" value="wissen">
<input id="vlag"  type="hidden" name="lang" class="nl" value="<?=$_GET["lang"]?>">
</form>
<div id="outer">
<div id="inner">
    <iframe name="Mediframe" width="800" height="600" frameborder=0>
    </iframe>
</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

tabel.php

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Medispeak</title>
    <link rel=stylesheet href=ProjectCSS.css>
</head>
```

```
$zoek = $_POST['zoek'];

switch ($_POST['lang']) {
case "1":
    try {
        $sQuery = "SELECT Medibijsluiter
    FROM Medispeak
    WHERE Medinaam LIKE ?";

        $oStmt = $db->prepare($sQuery);
        $oStmt->bindValue(1, "%$zoek%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $oStmt->execute();
        if ($oStmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            echo '<table border="2">';
            echo '<thead>';
            echo '<td>Medibijsluiter</td>';
            echo '</thead>';
            while ($aRow = $oStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>' . $aRow['Medibijsluiter'] . '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
            echo '</table>';
        } else {
            echo 'Helaas,geen gegevens bekend';
        }

    } catch
    (PDOException $e) {
        $sMsg = '<p>
    Regelnummer: ' . $e->getLine() . '<br />
    Bestand: ' . $e->getFile() . '<br />
    Foutmelding: ' . $e->getMessage() . '
    </p>';

        trigger_error($sMsg);
    }
    $db = null;
    break;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

But you can do it more cleaner. you should use a select imput within your second form :)